# Having trouble installing Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

While installing Microsoft Visual Studio Code, I received this message:

[image: message]

"Setup was unable to automatically close all applications. It is recommended that you close all applications using files that need to be updated by Setup before continuing."

How do I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps:

1. try to start setup as an administration
2. make sure you have closed the explorer, especially if you have opened anything related to C: drive.
3. If it still shows any problem, try to restart the system as some process is running in the background that holding onto some file that needs to modified by vscode setup.
4. try to disable Antivirus (last attempt).
5. try to install System installer of vscode instead of User setup (if you have downloaded user setup)

Comment: I tried to install the program today before trying any of these solutions, and for some reason, this message didn't pop up. Maybe it has something to do with the shutdown and startup of the computer. Thanks anyway!